# CSS 3 - Transition list item when resize parent div

Tags: css, transition

I have a image list(ul) inside a div. I want effect transition (css3) occurs when resize div parent and images change position. please help me!

I tried.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul class="listimg">
        <li><img src="icon1.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="icon2.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="icon3.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="icon4.png" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="icon5.png" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and css

```
#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.listimg{
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.listimg li{
    float: left;
    margin:30px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Updated...

Comment: What have you done/tried so far, please update the question..